# send email when blob is uploaded to azure blob storage using sendgrid in python

Tags: azure, twilio, sendgrid

I tried in dotnet and it is sending mail. But I need in python

```
#r "SendGrid"
using System;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
public static void Run(string myBlob,string name, ILogger log, out SendGridMessage
message)
{

message = new SendGridMessage();

message.PlainTextContent= "File has been updated/added to the blob : "+name ;
}
```

I am not getting how to do in python

Comment: In the docs you can choose your language and get a [python example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-sendgrid?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-python#example)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.